# How to disable Stream in Django

Tags: django, getstream-io, stream-django

I am trying to temporarily prevent [stream_django](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django) from making any remote API calls for offline development and testing purposes.

What is the easiest way to completely disable remote connections to the upstream API servers?

I found [feed_manager.disable_model_tracking()](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django/search?q=disable_model_tracking) which seems to prevent [Activity](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django/blob/master/stream_django/activity.py#L33-L128) updates, but it doesn't prevent all upstream calls (`feed_manager.follow_user()` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stream_django](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django) allows you to use a custom feed manager class via the `STREAM_FEED_MANAGER_CLASS` Django setting; that's probably the simplest way to skip follow/unfollow requests.

```
# yoursettings.py
STREAM_FEED_MANAGER_CLASS = "mymodule.TestFeedManager"

# mymodule/__init__.py
from stream_django import managers

class TestFeedManager(managers.FeedManager):

    def follow_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def unfollow_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Another approach, perhaps more powerful (and complex) is to use the [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) library to stub the manager or similar approach.

Comment: I had to surround `mymodule.TestFeedManager` in quotes to avoid import issues, but otherwise this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!